# mysqli overwriting empty posts with alternate variables from php

Tags: php, forms, validation, mysqli

I would like to write over empty variables if the form is submitted and user's do not fill out all the forms.

my mysqli query looks something like this

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO test (msg, name, time)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST[msg],$_POST[name],$_POST[main]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Now in simple what i'd like is: if a user doesn't fill out the name for it to return as anonymous... and If the user doesn't fill out the  msg I'd like to fill it out with  the variable `$cit`

I tried a few things however nothing yielded succesful... What i tried

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['msg'])){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', 'anonymous');
    }      
}
```

etc etc

I tried putting that code both above and below the query, but nothing happened.

Comment: _"...nothing happened."_ - ? What does that mean? What gets inserted in the database?

Comment: if you submit $_POST['msg'] with nothing in it, it goes in to the database with nothing in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `bind_param()`, you must bind with variables and not constants like numbers or string literals (eg `'anonymous'`).

I'd recommend building up some default values and then overwriting those with values from `$_POST`, for example

```
$defaults = array(
    'msg'  => $cit,
    'name' => 'anonymous',
    'main' => 'some other value'
);

$values = array_merge($defaults, array_filter($_POST));

// snip

$stmt->bind_param('sss', $values['msg'], $values['name'], $values['main']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong idea.

The rule of thumb is: **format your data at output**, not at input.

So, just let it go into database as is. When it's time to echo it out - format it whatever way you want - "anonymous" or some image or whatever. It's actually **view** responsibility, and all this stuff has nothing to do with database.

Thus, all you need is just to write everything you've got into table. However, to implement it using mysqli would be a PAIN. That's why you have to make it with PDO (though a little helper function still required too), which will allow you to bind an array of arbitrary size easily

A solution, based on the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) (scroll to the very bottom):

```
// First, list all the fields a user allowed to
$allowed = array("col1","col2","col3");

// next, create a SET statement query dynamically
// as well as create an array of values 
$set = pdoSet($fields,$values, $update);

// finally, run your dynamically built query
$sql = "UPDATE users SET $set WHERE id = :id";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($values);
```

Comment: Ofcourse, I just dummied down the question to make it more easy to answer. The question is out of context however the answer @Phil gave me was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Isn't this question regarding mysqli, While it's better to use PDO why are you answering a separate question?